# A claim could not be found for lookup claim with id "objectId" defined in technical profile with id "AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" policy

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I've followed the B2C - ADFS article.

I connect to ADFS, authenticate successfully but then B2C throws the above error.

I am using the latest SocialandLocalAccounts template.

My XML in the Extensions XML.

```
<ClaimsProvider>
            <Domain>ABC.com</Domain>
            <DisplayName>ABC ADFS</DisplayName>
            <TechnicalProfiles>
                <TechnicalProfile Id="ABC-SAML2">
                    <DisplayName>ABC staff</DisplayName>
                    <Description>Login with your ADFS account</Description>
                    <Protocol Name="SAML2"/>
                    <Metadata>
                        <Item Key="WantsEncryptedAssertions">false</Item>
                        <Item Key="PartnerEntity">https://my-adfs.southeastasia.cloudapp.azure.com/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml</Item>
                        <Item Key="XmlSignatureAlgorithm">Sha256</Item>
                    </Metadata>
                    <CryptographicKeys>
                        <Key Id="SamlAssertionSigning" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_SamlCert"/>
                        <Key Id="SamlMessageSigning" StorageReferenceId="B2C_1A_SamlCert"/>
                    </CryptographicKeys>
                    <OutputClaims>
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="userPrincipalName" />
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="given_name"/>
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" PartnerClaimType="family_name"/>
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" PartnerClaimType="email"/>
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="name"/>
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="ABC.com" />
                        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" DefaultValue="socialIdpAuthentication"/>
                    </OutputClaims>
                    <OutputClaimsTransformations>
                        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName"/>
                        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName"/>
                        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId"/>
                        <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId"/>
                    </OutputClaimsTransformations>
                    <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-Noop"/>
                </TechnicalProfile>
            </TechnicalProfiles>
        </ClaimsProvider>
    </ClaimsProviders>

    <UserJourneys>

        <UserJourney Id="SignUpSignInADFS">
            <OrchestrationSteps>
                <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
                    <ClaimsProviderSelections>
                        <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
                        <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="ABCExchange" />
                    </ClaimsProviderSelections>
                    <ClaimsExchanges>
                        <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
                    </ClaimsExchanges>
                </OrchestrationStep>
                <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
                    <Preconditions>
                        <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
                            <Value>objectId</Value>
                            <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
                        </Precondition>
                    </Preconditions>
                    <ClaimsExchanges>
                        <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" />
                        <ClaimsExchange Id="ABCExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="ABC-SAML2" />
                    </ClaimsExchanges>
                </OrchestrationStep>
                <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="ClaimsExchange">
                    <ClaimsExchanges>
                        <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
                    </ClaimsExchanges>
                </OrchestrationStep>
                <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />
            </OrchestrationSteps>
            <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
        </UserJourney>
    </UserJourneys>
```

This is what is returned in the SAML token from ADFS:

```
<AttributeStatement>
            <Attribute Name="userPrincipalName">
                <AttributeValue>user1@test.dev.com</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute Name="family_name">
                <AttributeValue>Test</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute Name="given_name">
                <AttributeValue>User1</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute Name="email">
                <AttributeValue>user1@company.com</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name">
                <AttributeValue>User1 Test</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
            <Attribute Name="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress">
                <AttributeValue>user1@company.com</AttributeValue>
            </Attribute>
        </AttributeStatement>
```

Comment: Hi @nzpcmad. You aren't creating a **user** object for the AD FS identity after orchestration step 2 so orchestration step 3 is failing because the **objectId** claim doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks. I see what I did wrong. I was trying to use LocalAccounts not realising that federation actually counts as "social". You need to use SocialAndLocalAccounts. I've suggested to the docs team that they make this clearer. The ADFS document assumes that you have done the "Getting Started" flow and that is based on SocialAndLocalAccounts.

Comment: Also, as per the documentation, the first output claim is "issuerUserId" but if you use the VS Code B2C extension to generate the template, the first claim is "socialIdpUserId"?

Comment: And the Salesforce example also uses "socialIdpUserId".

Comment: I suggest you should standardize on "issuerUserId" rather than "socialIdpUserId".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As above, make sure you are using "SocialAndLocalAccounts".

Comment: I know this is old, but do you have any detail on what exactly it was that you changed? Did you just start entirely over with the 'SocialAndLocalAccounts' starter pack [from here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack)?

Comment: Yes. There are more docs now - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-adfs?pivots=b2c-custom-policy. Note that ADFS has a claims rule for UPN and in the custom policy, it is mapped to "issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="upn".